# Views Display output in tpl file not working

Tags: views, theming

I'm making use of views 2.xx and pressflow 6.xx and i'v a little issue when it comes to the views Display output template file, it just won't show the rows when i tried to print them like this:

```
      <?php print $fields["field_genre_value"]->content; ?>
      <?php print $rows["field_genre_value"]->content; ?>
```

Non of them work....

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer, the best thing I've found to do in cases like these is to put a

```
<?php drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($rows, TRUE) . '</pre>'); ?>
```

in the template to see what you have to work with.  But if you are talking about the Display template, I am pretty sure by that point the `$rows` variable has been populated with HTML so you may need to look at another template if you want to get fancier with the output.